# countdown.js error, "Uncaught ReferenceError: countdown is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use [Countdown.js](http://countdownjs.org/). I found [this guide](https://blog.smalldo.gs/2013/12/create-simple-countdown/) and copied the code and pasted it to try to tweak and understand the code, but when i run it in [my web](http://monopolo11.ninja/tests/countdown..html) i cant make it work, in the console i get "Uncaught *ReferenceError: countdown is not defined(anonymous function) @ countdown..html:46*".

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="countdown.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://monopolo11.ninja/tests/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flip/flipclock.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="countdown-holder"></div>
    <script>
  var clock = document.getElementById("countdown-holder")
    , targetDate = new Date(2050, 00, 01); // Jan 1, 2050;

  clock.innerHTML = countdown(targetDate).toString();
  setInterval(function(){
    clock.innerHTML = countdown(targetDate).toString();
  }, 1000);
</script>
<br/>
<br/>
You will be logged out in <span id="logout-timer"></span>
<script>
  var timer = document.getElementById("logout-timer")
    , now = new Date()
    , deadline = new Date(now.getFullYear, now.getMonth, now.getDate, now.getHours, now.getMinutes + 15);

  timer.innerHTML = countdown(deadline).toString();
  setInterval(function(){
    timer.innerHTML = countdown(deadline ).toString();
  }, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample in guide use **c**ountdown is actually should be **C**ountdown.

```
// Declare the countdown object
// Constructor. target_date and current_date are Javascript Date objects
function Countdown(target_date, current_date) {
    this.target_date = target_date;
    this.current_date = current_date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that error!!
Can you help me with the new error please? 
"countdown..html:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined(anonymous function) @ countdown..html:22
countdown..html:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined(anonymous function) @ countdown..html:35"

Comment: You should post your code to some place like http://jsfiddle.net/ to make other people check where the problem is.